# init a spring bean from web.xml

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I am updating an existing Java EE web application that uses Spring.

In my web.xml, there is a servlet defined as follows:

```
  <servlet>
    <display-name>My Example Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MyExampleServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.MyExampleServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
```

now, in this class I need to add an @Autowite annotation:

```
class MyExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Autowired (required = true)
    MyExampleBean myExampleBean;

    [...]
}
```

the problem is that MyExampleBean is initialized by the Application Server
(in my case, weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.getNewInstance...)

so, Spring is not aware of that, and Spring does not have a chance to wire "myExampleBean".

How to solve that?
that is, how I need to modify web.xml or MyExampleServlet so that MyExampleServlet gets the reference to myExampleBean?

A possibility would be to add this init code inside MyExampleServlet,
but it requires a reference to servletContext. How to get a reference to servletContext?

```
ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
myExampleBean = (MyExampleBean) context.getBean("myExampleBean");
```

Answer (score 2):

I see, HttpServlet/GenericServlet has a getServletContext() method,
(and the application server calls first the servlet's init(ServletConfig config), and config contains a reference to servletContext).

See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html

The code modified:

```
class MyExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    MyExampleBean myExampleBean;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
        myExampleBean = (MyExampleBean) context.getBean("myExampleBean");
    }

    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your application context xml, you need something like

```
<bean id="myExampleBean" class="path/to/myExampleBean">
```

Comment: i already have this. the problem is that Spring is not creating the instance of MyExampleServlet (it is Weblogic who creates it), and so, Spring is not autowiring myExampleBean.